# Obtaining caller's defined output array dimensions in XLL

Tags: c++, arrays, excel, xll

I'm modifying an existing XLL written in C++. The original code always produces a 1 column array as output.  I'm interested in making the output more flexible (say, as a row of cells rather than a column of cells).  When using this array function in Excel, it is entered as an array function (i.e., the user enters it to cover an array of cells, rather than just a single cell.)

I know how to return an array of particular dimensions.  But what I don't know is this:
In the C++ code, how can I obtain the dimensions of the cell array that the user defined when calling this function?  If I have this information, I can then populate row-wise or column-wise, depending on how the user defined his receiving array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You wish to use the xlfCaller callback function.

An example is in the XLW documentation:

http://sourceforge.net/p/xlw/mailman/xlw-users/?viewmonth=200808

But you will need to add a safety check (as suggested in the comments on the thread) because your function call be called from other places (e.g. VBA, function wizard).